# Implementing microservices architecture, managing its interdependencies

Tags: c#, microservices, domain-driven-design

Imagine a OAuth provider using microservices. We will have microservice for authorization endpoint, token endpoint etc.

For example, every endpoint is different microservice and most endpoints will need to retrieve client by id to authenticate request. So how should I share method to get client from database, model for client and all related to it entities?

How shall I share common methods and classes between microservices?

If microservice A depends on microservice B, then I need to do communication between them over HTTP or I just can add project reference? Or maybe situation where some microservice depends on another is bad and says that our services are too micro?

Does scenario where we use DDD in our microservices says that our microservices are too big (or it adds too many complexity)? If they are really micro, doesn't it mean that some simple folders like `Models`, `Services` and `Endpoints` are enough?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> So how should I share method to get client from database, model for client and all related to it entities?

You don't, because sharing database between microservices usually is a very bad practice in microservice architecure.

> How shall I share common methods and classes between microservices?

In general - you should not. You can maintain several libraries for contracts (but you should consider some kind of [Schema Registry](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74080975/2501279) first) and cross-cutting concerns, but that's it.

> If microservice A depends on microservice B,

The thing is that you should avoid services being depended on each other in traditional sense. Services should be as loosely coupled as possible

> then I need to do communication between them over HTTP

There are cases when you will need some kind of RPC but the general approach is to try avoid synchronous communication between services in favor of asynchronous one (i.e. via some message bus for example)

> I just can add project reference?

If you can add a reference from one microservice on another then you don't have microservices.

> If they are really micro, doesn't it mean

I would argue that term "microservice" is not that well defined in general and from place to place can differ vastly.

Note that the goal of microservice architecture is not to split every endpoint into separate service, actually it can be very counterproductive to do so. I would argue that the main goal is to split your system into loosely coupled or even independent components (ideally as small as possible), actually if you are finding that several components are tightly coupled there are cases when you can just unite them back (or rework architecture so they can be decoupled).

I highly recommend to study the following resources:

- [Building Microservices: Designing Fine-Grained Systems 1st Edition
  by Sam Newman](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1491950358)
- [microservices.io](https://microservices.io/patterns/index.html) (and Microservices Patterns: With Examples in Java by Chris Richardson)
- [Avoiding Microservice Megadisasters - Jimmy Bogard](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gfh-VCTwMw8)

Comment: 1. But what if most of microservices needs information about `client` that sent request. I need to build new microservice responsible for managing clients and use API to get information? 2. So how to structure solution that uses microservices? I thought I can use something like solution(*.sln)->src->folders with names of microservices->in every folder appropriate projects (*.csproj, like ServiceName.API, ServiceName.Infrastructure etc).

Comment: 1. It is rare that all microservices will need the same information, one of the common approaches is to duplicate the info (i.e. you stream changes to users via some message queue and all interested parties consume it and store the copy of data in their respective storages). 2. You can place them into one solution but then you need to monitor that there is no unwanted dependencies (i.e. one microservice does not reference another), another approach is to just have several solutions or even repositories (and solve contacts/corss-cutting concerns sharing via libraries or git submodules).

Comment: What about Shared project with common models (or even many shared projects which are more "minimal")? The microservices then doesn't depend on each other, but on some independant class-library project (I think it's similar to situation where every microservice references the same NuGet package). Is it bad?

Comment: @Szyszka947 yes, basically it is the idea behind the git submodules approach when you have different repositories - you have a common project which is distributed as submodule. Note that again "models" is the term I'm trying to avoid, because models is too broad I think, you want to share only public contracts (messages or stuff for RPC - like classes for http requests and responses, but in general you might want to have a more language-agnostic stuff, for example GRPC proto files or JSON schemas or something like RAML files)

Comment: Hm, can't understand why it's bad. This will be just project of POCO classes that do nothing. What are reasons to avoid it? If we modify some model in this project (I think about Shared project like DDD domain layer with entities only), probably we want to modify it in every microservice. If our microservices use different languages we can have as many models as languages. What's bad here.

Comment: @Szyszka947 at least one problem here - you will need to maintain the changes across all different languages, and it can quickly become quite cumbersome. If some team will decide to use a new language you will need to manually copy the models to the new language. But note that depends on your case. If homogeneous technological landscape and small team - you can be just fine with shared project (though a question arises are microservices justified in this case at all). There are a lot of factors which should be taken in account and without full knowledge I can give only pointers as in my answer

Comment: @Szyszka947 And to highlight - those in answer I consider being best practices for microservices but case to case they can differ depending on different restrictions and limitation you have. In my several projects which tried to use microservices approaches the ones which most leveraged it (in my opinion) were the ones which had some infrastructure to write contracts in language-agnostic ways and use some automation to build language-depended code. Though that was not feasible for all of them (time constraints, team sizes. etc.) so you can always have some trade offs and still have success.

Answer (score 1):

The point of microservices is that they should be *independent*. Meaning they can be developed and deployed independently. This may require that each service has a separate versioned, backwards compatible API. Separate databases, etc. Importantly it usually also means separate *teams*, using separate repositories, separate solutions, and possibly separate languages.

Sometimes an [API gateway](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/architect-microservice-container-applications/direct-client-to-microservice-communication-versus-the-api-gateway-pattern) is used to route requests to services, and this may do some things, like authentication.

Calling other services is not prohibited, and are done thru the public API of the service, whatever protocol that may use. If your services use HTTP you should call using HTTP. But you need to be careful to avoid cascades of calls that can absolutely ruin performance.